# Django delete foreign object?

Tags: django

If we set up a profile how Django recommends:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

Then when you delete the `User` object from Django admin, it deletes his profile too.This is because the profile has a foreign key to user and it wants to protect referential integrity. However, I want this functionality even if the pointer is going the other way. For example, on my `Profile` class I have:

```
shipper = models.ForeignKey(Shipper, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
carrier = models.ForeignKey(Carrier, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
affiliat = models.ForeignKey(Affiliate, unique=True, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Affiliate')
```

And I want it so that if you delete the `Profile` it'll delete the associated shipper/carrier/affiliate objects (don't ask me why Django made "affiliate" some weird keyword). Because shippers, carriers and affiliates are types of users, and it doesn't make sense for them to exist without the rest of the data (no one would be able to log in as one).

The reason I didn't put the keys on the other objects, is because then Django would have to internally join all those tables every time I wanted to check which type the user was...

Comment: "affiliate" is most certainly not "some kind of wierd keyword" in Django. I can create a model with a field named "affiliate" and work with it just fine in my code.

Comment: That's very weird. Everything works fine but it refuses to appear in the admin section. Did you check that? SVN checkout like a week ago.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While using a post_delete signal as described by bernardo above is an ok approach, that will work well, I try to avoid using signals as little as humanly possible as I feel like it convolutes your code unnecessarily by adding behavior to standard functionality in places that one might be expecting.

I prefer the overriding method above, however, the example given by Felix does have one fatal flaw; the delete() function it is overriding looks like this:

```
def delete(self, using=None):
    using = using or router.db_for_write(self.__class__, instance=self)
    assert self._get_pk_val() is not None, "%s object can't be deleted because its %s attribute is set to None." % (self._meta.object_name, self._meta.pk.attname)

    collector = Collector(using=using)
    collector.collect([self])
    collector.delete()
```

Notice the parameter 'using', in most cases we call delete() with empty arguments so we may have even known it was there.  In the above example this parameter is buried by us overriding and not looking at the superclass functionality, if someone where to pass the 'using' parameter when deleting Profile it will cause unexpected behavior.  To avoid that, we would make sure to preserve the argument along with its default lika so:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
# ...

def delete(self, using=None):
    if self.shipper:
        self.shipper.delete()
    if self.carrier:
        self.carrier.delete()
    if self.affiliat:
        self.affiliat.delete()
    super(Profile, self).delete(using)
```

One pitfall to the overriding approach, however, is that delete() does not get explicitly called per db record on bulk deletes, this means that if you are going to want to delete multiple Profiles at one time and keep the overriding behavior (calling .delete() on a django queryset for example) you will need to either leverage the delete signal (as described by bernardo) or you will need to iterate through each record deleting them individually (expensive and ugly).

Comment: no need to specify why you answer when answer is good, and you get credit for it too

Comment: Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Comment: @dnaranjo Yes, this is all laid out in the pitfalls listed at the end of my answer.  Thank you for commenting though, hopefully someone who doesn't read through the entire answer will notice the potential pitfalls by reading your comments, and will aid in making an educated decision for their individual needs.

Comment: Can you explain why do you set `using = None` ? I tried to find the meaning of this parameter but with no sucess so far.

Answer (score 9):

A better way to do this and that works with object's delete method and queryset's delete method is using the `post_delete` signal, as you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete).

In your case, your code would be quite similar to this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(models.signals.post_delete, sender=Profile)
def handle_deleted_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.shipper:
        instance.shipper.delete()
    if instance.carrier:
        instance.carrier.delete()
    if instance.affiliat:
        instance.affiliat.delete()
```

This works only for Django 1.3 or greater because the `post_delete` signal was added in this Django version.

Answer (score 5):

You can [override the `delete()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete) method of the Profile class and delete the other objects in this method before you delete the actual profile.

Something like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # ...

    def delete(self):
        if self.shipper:
            self.shipper.delete()
        if self.carrier:
            self.carrier.delete()
        if self.affiliat:
            self.affiliat.delete()
        super(Profile, self).delete()
```

Comment: Looks good, but the `delete()` method never seems to get called when I delete stuff through the Django admin...?

Comment: @Mark: It should at least work when you delete a single object. With deleting multiple objects there seems to be an issue: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10751